# How to determine Flash size?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, nodemcu

I need to determine the flash size of my ESP8266 on my NodeMCU module in order to flash the AT firmware onto the board. Apparently different boards come with differently-sized flash memories. Can anyone tell me the easiest way to find the flash size?

Comment: By reading the manual for your NodeMCU. Which version is it?

Comment: It's Version 1.0

Comment: The version 1.0 uses the ESP-12E which has 4MB flash.

Comment: `esptool.py -p COM5 -c esp8266 flash_id` (you can find esptool inside ESP-IDF SDK components/esptool_py)

Comment: use ESP.getFlashChipRealSize()  in your code.

Answer (score 10):

Arduino's ESP8266 support includes an example sketch called **CheckFlashConfig**. This probes the board, and prints the flash memory size.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way (windows at least) is to use Espressif's [flash download tool](https://espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools) - don't select anything to flash to the device, select the appropriate com port, click start, and the details of the device will appear in the Detected Info window